# Google Maps key in AndroidManifest.xml from google-services.json

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-manifest, google-play-services

I have a `google-services.json` file that contains the API key for, amongst other things, the google maps service.  Google maps requires the following information in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="KEY_GOES_HERE" />
```

I can access the information in Java using `R.string.google_api_key`, as the build process turns the JSON file into resources as per https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin, but is there a way to refer to the key inside the manifest file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_api_key"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  IntelliJ shows this as an error but it does build and indeed work.

Comment: Works here too. I found that adding the following Lint tag will suppress error-reporting at the tag level:

<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->

Comment: Also you can override `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` in `android/app/build.gradle` by adding string

`resValue 'string', 'com.google.android.geo.API_KEY', '<Specify your api key here>'`
 to `defaultConfig` or `productFlavors.<YouFlavor>`